# Color coding Invoke-SQL in Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

Using invoke-sql I have a PowerShell script that returns results from a SQL Query.  That query has the status of several data points local I want to colour code the entire row if the column of Status returns different values.  Is this possible as I know you can colour code Charts in PowerShell but not sure how a larger return query would work?

```
    param(
    [string] $dataSource = "SQLName",
    [string] $database = "DatabaseName",
    [string] $sqlCommand = $("Select tbldatafeed.datafeed_name,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tbldatafeedhistory.status_id,1,'Running'),2,'Completed'),3,'Faulted'),4,'Warning'),5,'Terminating'),6,'Terminated'),7,'Pending') AS Status,DateDiff(MINUTE,tbldatafeedhistory.start_time, tbldatafeedhistory.end_time) As 'Run Time(minutes)'
    from tblDataFeedHistory
    left Join tblDatafeed on tbldatafeedhistory.datafeed_id = tbldatafeed.datafeed_id
    inner join 
    (
        Select max(start_time) as LatestDate, [datafeed_id]
        from tblDataFeedHistory
        Group by datafeed_id
    ) SubMax 
    on tblDataFeedHistory.start_time = SubMax.LatestDate
    and tblDataFeedHistory.datafeed_id = SubMax.datafeed_id 
    WHERE tbldatafeed.is_active = 1
    Order by tbldatafeed.datafeed_id")
    )

    $connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource; " + "Integrated Security=SSPI; " + "Initial Catalog=$database"
    $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
    $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
    $connection.Open()

    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    write-output $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

    $connection.Close()
    $dataSet.Tables
    }

    $FeedID = Invoke-SQL
    $FeedID
```

The output would be a red highlighted line if the column returned Failed, yellow if the Column returns Warning, Green if the column returns Completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not personally found or seen a reason to do this with SQL data generally, nor do I have any record in my stash of anyone who has.

Anything you write to the screen can have color. It's one of the primary focuses of the …

```
[Write-Host][1]
```

Or 
    [Console]::ForegroundColor]

...   [cmdlet or .Net class](https://www.petri.com/change-powershell-console-font-and-background-colors).

However, if you plan to use that data on the pipeline, or elsewhere, then don't use it. Especially if you are not on the newest PowerShell versions. Legacy PowerShell, Write-Host empties the buffer, later PowerShell versions, send it to the Information Stream. As talked by PowerShell inventor Jeffery Snover here:.

> http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful
>
> ... Jeffrey Snover change his stance on this as of May 2016.
>
> With PowerShell v5 Write-Host no longer "kills puppies". data is
>   captured into info stream ...
>
> https://twitter.com/jsnover/status/727902887183966208
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Information?view=powershell-5.1

However, there are PowerShell modules you can leverage to get really creative with color.

```
Find-Module -Name '*color*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You also have several scripts to leverage as is or tweak for your use case.

[Format Table Colors in PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Format-Table-Colors-in-e0a4beac)
Format the output table colors in PowerShell host with/without conditional colorful formatting.

Download : [Write-PSObject.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Format-Table-Colors-in-e0a4beac/file/170320/9/Write-PSObject.ps1)

You do have another option. If you want to call attention, with color to a given screen output line, you can use the ...

```
Write-Warning 
Write-Error
```

... cmdlets and just accept its default color.

Yet, your question could almost be a duplicate of these Q&A and its accepted answer.

[Powershell - Output Color for certain results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016763/powershell-output-color-for-certain-results)

[Is there a way to specify a font color when using write-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647756/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-font-color-when-using-write-output)

If you are saying, that you are sending this to a form, then you have to handle color in the form properties code.