# How to save color of string into variables

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell 5.1, and I want to store some colored text into a variable. I'm aware that you can use `Write-Host` to print out some colored strings into the console, as shown below:

[image]

However, I can't seem to save them into a variable:

[image]

I've tried various solutions such as the ones given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647756/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-font-color-when-using-write-output) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: if you are using a console/terminal that supports ANSI color codes ... you can save those strings with the color codes. the new-ish windows terminal supports ANSI color codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PowerShell ANSI escape sequences with the format:

`$([char]0x1b)[#m`

where `#` represents a number. (see [here](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797) for more info about ANSI escape sequences)

In the case of the question above, it would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can store the parameter arguments you need for `Write-Host` in a variable:

```
$hi = @{ Object = 'hi!'; ForegroundColor = 'Red' }

# ... later
Write-Host @hi
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the attempt to assign the text output to a variable, `$hi = Write-Host ...`, is because `Write-Host` doesn't *return* the text it prints - it sends the text with ANSI color codes to the console.

You could figure out a convenient scheme for including color information in the text you want to print, and write code that uses that color information as it prints the text to the screen, as suggested by the other posted answer.

For instance,

```
$text = @'
  { 
    "text": [["The quick ", "red"], ["brown fox ", "blue"], 
             ["jumped over ", "yellow"], ["the lazy ", "cyan"], 
             ["dog", "white"]]
  }
'@
($text | ConvertFrom-Json).text |
         % { Write-Host $_[0] -ForegroundColor $_[1] -NoNewLine }
```

This could be pretty tedious though. Maybe check [PSGallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) to see if there are any packages dealing with colorized text that provide commands convenient for your application.